# woocommerce-кнопка заказать при отсутствии товара в наличии

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как реализовать появление кнопки "заказать" при статусе товара "нет в наличии" для woocommerce

Answer (score 1):

На странице товара используется шаблон для кнопки wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\add-to-cart\simple.php   его можно изменить если скопировать в тему в папку woocommerce\single-product\add-to-cart\simple.php `

```
<?php if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

    <form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

        <?php
            if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                    'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 1, $product ),
                    'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity(), $product ),
                    'input_value' => ( isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : 1 )
                ) );
            }
        ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />

        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
    </form>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<button>Заказать</button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`